# Support Heroku webhook from github?

Tags: heroku, github, webhooks

I can not find documentation about integration Heroku with github webhook.

Github have Webhook service which allows rebuild application when you push new commit to github repository. Have Heroku native support webhook from github for rebuild project?
Or how I can do it simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a thing doesn't exist on Heroku.

Heroku only support pushes via Git (and a new push mechanism in beta). Some Cloud providers provide you with a POST url which you can link Github to put ping when a push occur which then triggers the cloud provider to retrieve the latest code but Heroku does not provide this.

You would have to use an interim CI service, something like codeship.io which runs your tests and then will deploy to Heroku for you.

Comment: The semaphore add-on for heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo [gh-hk-deploy](https://github.com/lstoll/gh-hk-deploy)

Simple app that lets you deploy your app to Heroku when you push to GitHub. It will fetch code on change, and force push the master branch to Heroku.